# Angular - Webpage redirect to homepage when opening external url

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Whenever I open an external URL from my webpage, this webpage redirect to homepage. The external URL gets open in new tab but the webpage from which I am opening the external URL it redirect to homepage. I don't know why this is happening I tried all the possible but couldn't get rid of it.

```
xyz.html

<a (click)="goToLink('https://www.example.com/abc')">page link</a>

xyz.ts

goToLink(url: string) {
  window.open(url, "_blank");
}
```

Comment: Try changing the anchor tag to some other tag

Comment: Most likely because you are using `<a>` tag without `href`. Instead of (click) you can just do `<a href="https://www.indiantrain.in/flight-pnr-status" target="_blank">page link</a>`

Comment: If i am doing as your said it redirect to https://www.example.com/https:

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be some edge case behaviour you have there, but I would be using the `href` in the `a` tag for using an external URL.

Like this:
`<a href="https://www.example.com/abc">page Link</a>`

for internal routing with angular router:
`<a routerLink="/abc">page link</a>`

Comment: If i am doing as your said it redirect to https://www.example.com/https: